# Sharing an asp.net mvc application in local network

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, networking, windows-8

i did an asp.net mvc4 application of project management . I'd like to test it in local network.So i need to know how can i share it in local network and make a machine as a server ( the database will be in it). All the machines are windows8 64 bits .

In my firewall configuration window i have this:
[image: im]
So:

1. How can i share the application to be visible in the local network?
2. How can i configure the `iis` server to accept the share?
3. If i choose my machine as a server, how can i let the others users modify the database by using this application?

Comment: Setting up a website is more of an Administrative task, so this might be a better fit over at http://www.ServerFault.com  I's also a bit broad.  If you need to do this yourself, I'd start by looking at the [IIS documentation](http://www.iis.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really inst a simple way to answer this, but I did a google search and came up with this link. It provides a fast and easy way to host an intranet site with IIS.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/configure-iis-to-host-a-simple-intranet-website.aspx

1. See the link
2. See the link
3. This is more of a DNS issue, but you can always provide the ip address for the end user to test.

Comment: plz see my edit, i had a firewall configuration problem: only public and private option!!

Comment: Lol you really removed marking the answer.. So what is your new question?

Comment: lol I'm sorry:see my edit when i'd changing the firewall configuration i didn't find the "Domain" option (i'm using windows8)

Comment: Is your computer on a domain? If not just check private.

Comment: What do you mean by Domain?

Comment: If you don't know, then just check private.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37053/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-dunbar)